# I am having a problem with my python program that im running

Tags: python, programming-languages

From an input file I'm suppose to extract only first name of the student and then save the result in a new file called "student-­‐firstname.txt" The output file should contain a list of
first names (not include middle name). I was able to get delete of the last name but I'm having problem deleting the middle name any help or suggestion?

the student name in the file look something like this (last name, first name, and middle initial)

> Martin, John
>
> Smith, James W.
>
> Brown, Ashley S.

my python code is:

```
f=open("studentname.txt", 'r')

f2=open ("student-firstname.txt",'w')

str = ''

for line in f.readlines():

     str = str + line

     line=line.strip()

     token=line.split(",")

     f2.write(token[1]+"\n")

f.close()

f2.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f=open("studentname.txt", 'r')
f2=open ("student-firstname.txt",'w')

for line in f.readlines():
     token=line.split()
     f2.write(token[1]+"\n")
f.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: thank you Tom for the help it works. it's a lot easier than i made the program to be.

Comment: use `with` statement; don't use `.readlines()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366471/i-am-having-a-problem-with-my-python-program-that-im-running/5366685#5366685

Comment: I was just fixing the code so that it would work, but your solution is defiantly the "right" way to do it if this were a real program and not a simple I/O exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Split token[1] with space.

```
fname = token[1].split(' ')[0]
```

Comment: i tired that but it didn't work my fname was empty after i open it. thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("studentname.txt") as f, open("student-firstname.txt", 'w') as fout:
    for line in f:
        firstname = line.split()[1]
        print >> fout, firstname
```

Note:

- you could use a `with` statement to make sure that the files are always closed even in case of an exception. You might need [`contextlib.nested()`](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nested) on old Python versions
- `'r'` is a default mode for files. You don't need to specify it explicitly
- `.readlines()` reads all lines at once. You could iterate over the file line by line directly

To avoid hardcoding the filenames you could use [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html). Save it to `firstname.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    firstname = line.split()[1]
    print firstname
```

Example: `$ python firstname.py studentname.txt >student-firstname.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Check out [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). Something like this will probably work:

```
>>> import re
>>> nameline = "Smith, James W."
>>> names = re.match("(\w+),\s+(\w+).*", nameline)
>>> if names:
...     print names.groups()
('Smith', 'James')
```

Line 3 basically says find a sequence of word characters as group 0, followed by a comma, some space characters and another sequence of word characters as group 1, followed by anything in `nameline`.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("file")
o = open("out","w")
for line in f:
    o.write(line.rstrip().split(",")[1].strip().split()+"\n")
f.close()
o.close()
```